# git commit error: pathspec 'xxx' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I wrote a bash script to update my files through git automatically, but I keep getting error for the git commit line, if my message contains error.

I have already wrapped my message with quote, what's wrong here?

My bash script:

```
##Handle local git update
remote='
cd express-demo-nonbare;
git pull origin master;
';

echo "Process for updating Git begin";
git add . ;
read -p "Message for this commit: " comment;
comment=\"${comment}\";
echo $comment;
git commit --message=$comment;
git push backup master;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you just need to quote the `comment` variable when supplying it to `git commit`.  You can replace:

```
read -p "Message for this commit: " comment;
comment=\"${comment}\";
echo $comment;
git commit --message=$comment;
```

with

```
read -p "Message for this commit: " comment;
echo $comment;
git commit --message="$comment";
```

The quotes will not be part of the commit message, rather they are consumed by `bash` in ensuring that the entire content of the `comment` variable is submitted as part of a single `--message=...` argument to `git`, even if it contains whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to, as you put it:

> wrap... my message with quote

(which is indeed what you are doing).  Instead, you want to *protect* your message from having bash treat it as a *list of words*.  To do that, you need quotes, but in a different position:

```sh
remote='
cd express-demo-nonbare;
git pull origin master;
'

echo "Process for updating Git begin"
git add .
read -p "Message for this commit: " comment
echo "$comment"
git commit --message="$comment"
git push backup master
```

I removed all non-essential semicolons as well (bash treats the end of a line as the end of the command, unless something like an unclosed parenthesis or brace prevents this).

It's not clear to me what your intent is in setting the variable `remote` to the literal string <kbd>newline</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>...<kbd>;</kbd><kbd>newline</kbd>, especially since `$remote` does not occur later in the script.  Note, however, that since this string does include white-space, expanding it *outside* quotes, as in `$remote` (vs `"$remote"` which expands it inside quotes) can trigger further shell actions.  For instance:

```
foo='this; that'
wc $foo
```

will have the `wc` program attempt to open files named `this;` and `that`, having split `$foo` at the white spaces into separate words that are then passed to `wc`.  This splitting is actually based on `$IFS`:

```
IFS=+
foo='this+that'
wc $foo
```

tries to open files named `this` and `that`.  Restoring IFS to its normal setting:

```
wc $foo
```

tries to open one file named `this+that`.

(I sometimes use `wc` as a program to help show what the actual arguments were, since it tries to open each one as a file name, and spits out the actual file name in any subsequent error message or count.)

Similarly, if the expansion of a variable produces shell glob metacharacters, these will be evaluated after the expansion:

```
foo='*'
wc $foo
```

will try to open and read every file and directory in the current directory.  Again, double quotes will protect against this:

```
wc "$foo"
```

will only try to open and read one file, named `*`.